# Werkzeug server is shutting down in Django application

Tags: python, django, werkzeug

after updating the Werkzeug version from 2.0.3 to 2.1.0, I keep getting errors every time I run the server, and here is the error log:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 44612)                                                                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread                                                                                                                           
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request                                                                                                                                   
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)                                                                                                                                                
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__                                                                                                                                         
    self.handle()                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/oladhari/.virtualenvs/reachat/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 363, in handle                                                                                          
    super().handle()                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/server.py", line 427, in handle                                                                                                                                            
    self.handle_one_request()                                                                                                                                                                              
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/server.py", line 415, in handle_one_request                                                                                                                                
    method()                                                                                                                                                                                               
  File "/home/oladhari/.virtualenvs/reachat/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 243, in run_wsgi                                                                                        
    self.environ = environ = self.make_environ()                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/oladhari/.virtualenvs/reachat/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_extensions/management/commands/runserver_plus.py", line 326, in make_environ                                                
    del environ['werkzeug.server.shutdown']                                                                                                                                                                
KeyError: 'werkzeug.server.shutdown'
```

this exception keep appearing while incrementing by 2 ( ('127.0.0.1', 44612) ->  ('127.0.0.1', 44628)  and the server crash

checking the changes log, I have found this detail:

```
Remove previously deprecated code. #2276

Remove the non-standard shutdown function from the WSGI environ when running the development server. See the docs for alternatives.
```

here is the link to the [changes log](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/changes/#version-2-1-0)

it asks to check the [documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/) for alternatives but can not find any

please let me know how I would resolve this error, thank you
NB: my python version is 3.8

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Literally just ran into this today. According to their ([git repo issue 1715](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/1715)) and assuming you are running `runserver_plus`, there are three options that worked for some users. The first worked for me:

1. Not altering your files and adding the option `--keep-meta-shutdown`. My full command looks like `python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file /path/to/cert.pem --key-file /path/to/key.pem --keep-meta-shutdown localhost:9000`
2. Comment out open lines 325 and 326 under your runserver_plus.py
3. Upgrading python to 3.10

Hope this helps!

Comment: Upgrading to Python 3.11 worked for me.
And also make sure that Werkzeug is allowed to update to the latest version too.
Do not run `Werkzeug==2.0.*`

Answer (score 4):

The [Django-extensions issue](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/1715) for this recommends running runserver_plus with the `--keep-meta-shutdown` argument.

Alternatively, you can just downgrade Werkzeug to 2.0.* until this is fixed:

```
pip install Werkzeug==2.0.*
```

If using a requirements.txt file, use the following:

```
Werkzeug==2.0.*
```